# Updating values instead of NULLs

Tags: sql, oracle, null

I'm using Oracle SQL.

I have the following table:

```
Timestamp             | A   | B
13-11-14 06.49.54.004 | 50  | 70
13-11-14 06.49.54.005 | NULL| 80
13-11-14 06.49.54.006 | NULL| NULL
13-11-14 06.49.54.007 | 40  | 70
13-11-14 06.49.54.008 | 20  | 90
13-11-14 06.49.54.009 | 30  | NULL
```

How can i replace the `NULL` values with the last values of each column? Here is the expected output table:

```
Timestamp             | A   | B
13-11-14 06.49.54.004 | 50  | 70
13-11-14 06.49.54.005 | 50  | 80
13-11-14 06.49.54.006 | 50  | 80
13-11-14 06.49.54.007 | 40  | 70
13-11-14 06.49.54.008 | 20  | 90
13-11-14 06.49.54.009 | 30  | 90
```

Please advise.

Comment: Do you want to update your source table, or just replace nulls when querying?

Comment: I want to create a new table with the expected result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [the `first_value()` analytic function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25554/analysis.htm#sthref1167) with a windowing clause, using the timestamp column for ordering and ignoring nulls:

```
select timestamp, a, b,
  first_value(a) ignore nulls over (order by timestamp desc
    rows between current row and unbounded following) as new_a,
  first_value(b) ignore nulls over (order by timestamp desc
    rows between current row and unbounded following) as new_b
from table_name
order by timestamp;

TIMESTAMP                             A          B      NEW_A      NEW_B
---------------------------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
13-NOV-14 06.49.54.004000000         50         70         50         70 
13-NOV-14 06.49.54.005000000                    80         50         80 
13-NOV-14 06.49.54.006000000                               50         80 
13-NOV-14 06.49.54.007000000         40         70         40         70 
13-NOV-14 06.49.54.008000000         20         90         20         90 
13-NOV-14 06.49.54.009000000         30                    30         90
```

Or going the other way with last_value() instead:

```
select timestamp, a, b,
  last_value(a) ignore nulls over (order by timestamp
    rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as new_a,
  last_value(b) ignore nulls over (order by timestamp
    rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as new_b
from table_name
order by timestamp;
```

The window includes the current row, so if that value is not null then it will be used; otherwise it'll use the first/last not-null value (because of the `ignore null` clause) as it traverses the window in the specified order.

Comment: Thanks. My table have more than 240k records, and the query runs too much time. Does it makes sense?

Comment: @Omri - this approach only hits the table once, so I don't think you'd get much faster. These functions are designed for large data volumes. 240k isn't many really - how long does it take, and why is it too slow if it's a one-off task? I guess I'm assuming you're querying a single table rather than the data you show being the result of joins against multiple tables; if it is then you'd need to look at the execution plan, as for any other query.

Answer (score 1):

Use coalesce to update NULL's only, use sub-selects to find most recent values.

```
update tablename t1 set a = coalesce(a,(select max(a) from tablename
                                        where Timestamp < t1.Timestamp)),
                        b = coalesce(b,(select max(b) from tablename
                                        where Timestamp < t1.Timestamp))
 where a is null or b is null
```

Now edited! (Max must perhaps not be most recent...)

```
update tablename t1 set a = coalesce(a,(select a from tablename
                                        where Timestamp < t1.Timestamp
                                        order by Timestamp desc
                                        fetch first 1 row only)),
                        b = coalesce(b,(select b from tablename
                                        where Timestamp < t1.Timestamp
                                        order by Timestamp desc
                                        fetch first 1 row only))
 where a is null or b is null
```

Newer Oracle version required for FETCH FIRST.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest two approaches.  First, you can do this with a PL/SQL block pretty easily, something like:

```
DECLARE
  v_prev_timestamp TIMESTAMP;
  v_prev_A INT;
  v_prev_B INT;
BEGIN
  FOR x IN (SELECT * FROM table_name) LOOP
    IF (x.A IS NULL) THEN
      UPDATE table_name SET A = v_prev_A where timestamp = v_prev_timestamp;
    END IF;
    ... same for B ...
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Alternatively, you could create a view using Oracle's LAG function that would cover up the nulls with the values from the previous rows.

```
CREATE VIEW table_name_no_nulls AS
  SELECT timestamp, 
      nvl(A, lag(A) OVER (ORDER BY timestamp)) AS A,
      nvl(B, lag(B) OVER (ORDER BY timestamp)) AS B
    FROM table_name;
```

In this second version, NVL looks for null values in the first parameter and if null replaces the value with the result of the input of the second parameter, which is the lagged value of the same column.  You have to tell Oracle how the table is ordered so that it knows which previous value to use.

I'd recommend using the second version as you don't need to run any one-time batches to update the data.  Just query a new view that transforms the nulls.

Comment: Also, I don't have access to Oracle right now so my syntax might be off a bit.

Comment: You're only looking back one row with lag though; so in the example data, the third row would still get a null for A.

Comment: Is it possible with LAST_VALUE()?

Answer (score 0):

There is a LEAD() and LAG() analytic functions. In your case you need LAG(). It is very easy to use, plenty examples - check documentation and search stackoverflow...